# Solve Equation from Table

Tags: calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have a table of $X$ values and $Y$ values, and I'm trying to figure out the equation to get from one to the other. What's absolutely throwing me for a loop is how $334$ and $331$ can both be maped to $160$. Maybe it's a tiered system, where every five values in $X$ correlate with a bump in the value of $Y$? I'm lost.

```
X 132 186 199 224 242 297 300 318 331 334 365
Y  77 101 108 102 130 142 150 156 160 160 170
```

Comment: Welcome to math.se! You need to add more context to the answer. I am guessing that the problem is that you are interpreting this as a system of linear equations, while the exercise actually asks for a linear regression. As you already figured out, this is overdetermined (and has no solution). In such cases one usually tries to find something that is as "close" as possible (usually in a least squares sense) to the plane spanned by this system (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this kind of function guessing problems can fall into the category of polynomial interpolation.

Let's say you start with a function $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$, and let $y = f(x)$ for easier notation, the answer is obvious:

$$f(x) = \frac{(y_1-y_0)}{(x_1-x_0)}(x-x_0) + y_0$$

Let's simplify it to

$$f(x) = p_0 x + k_0$$

Now you want to make $(x_2,y_2)$ also fitting to the above function. We add some things to $f(x)$ and call it $g(x)$

$$g(x) = f(x) + k*(x-x_1)*(x-x_0)$$

and try to figure out k by substituting new $g(x) = y_2$ and $x = x_2$. The later part is there because it could make the part $0$ if it uses older values that are already covered by $f(x)$, so the answer on $g(x)$ will be purely $f(x)$.

This can be done recursively for all data values. (And there are mechanical method to work it out too! Try to find it yourself!)

However this is not a good answer for statistical problem, since it totally ignores the fluctuation induced by higher degree.